# How to make my meta-aws compatible with my yocto

Tags: amazon-web-services, embedded-linux, yocto

first time publishing there !

I first want to say that I'm a real noob to yocto, and I'm trying to add greengrass to my yocto project.

The issue is, my core layer is thud, but there aren't any meta-aws in thud, starting at zeus.

How I can I still go though and install my meta-aws on my yocto ?

Thx,

Answer (score 1):

I found meta-aws available for thud [here](https://github.com/aws/meta-aws/tree/thud). Just `git clone -b thud git@github.com:aws/meta-aws.git` into your layers directory, then `bitbake-layers add-layer /path/to/meta-aws`, then you should be able to use their recipes.

Comment: Oh, i'll try this ! Thank you for the answer ! :)

Comment: Thank you the answer ! Unhopefully this thud version only supports greengrass 1.10 and I need greengrass >= 2.0.0, so it is not the right version for me. Is there a way to make a master branch compatible with a thud yocto ?

Comment: Not sure of what sort of limitations you have, but you should really try and get your project not using thud since it is EOL. You should be running dunfell at this point which has LTS. If you really can't update to dunfell, you might be able to create a custom recipe for greengrass >= 2.0.0 and specify the preferred version in your local.conf, but that's a bit messy and I probably wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: Thanks for  your precious help ! Actually, my company is using a yocto-thud and I can't change this unhopefully, so I have to adapt a greengrass (mayber dunfell, or master or whatever release that supports greengrass 2.0) to my yocto-thud, and it sounds to be a litle bit tricky, this is where i'm getting confused if it is possible or not :)